# Order date in React

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, react-context

I have the following code:

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { GlobalContext } from "../context/GlobalState";
import {Transaction} from "./Transaction";

export const TransactionList = () => {
  const { transactions } = useContext(GlobalContext);
  console.log(transactions);

 // Clear localStorage and the transaction list
  const clearTransactions = () => {
    localStorage.clear();
    window.location.reload();
  };


//The most recent transaction is up in the list
  const sortedTransactions = transactions.sort(
    (a, b) => b.date - a.date
  );

  return (
    <>
      <h3>History</h3>
      <button onClick={()=>clearTransactions()} className="btn">Clear History</button>
      <ul className="list">
      {/* retrieve transactions from localStorage  and order them by date*/}
      {transactions.length > 0 ? (
        sortedTransactions.map(transaction => (  // eslint-disable-line
          <Transaction key={transaction.id} transaction={transaction} />
        ))): (<h2 style={{textAlign: 'center'}}>No transactions</h2>)}: 
      
      </ul>
    </>
  );
};
```

I would like the most recent transaction to be placed high on the list.
The result I have is:
20/12/2021
25/12/2021
while I want the opposite to happen
25/12/2021
20/12/2021

```
16 //The most recent transaction is up in the list
17   const sortedTransactions = transactions.sort(
18     (a, b) => b.date - a.date
19   );
20   console.log(sortedTransactions);
21
22    const reverseTransactions = sortedTransactions.reverse();
23    console.log(reverseTransactions);
```

[image: Dates]

Comment: Have you tried sortedTransactions.reverse() after sorting it? I think it'll work, give it a try.

Comment: I tried but it doesn't function

Comment: Can you try to check what type of the sortedTransactions is? If it's an object, it clearly can do the reverse one and it can solve your problem really quick. If it's not I guess we have to find a way to workaround.

Comment: @Bunny it's an object

Comment: Weird, then tried reverseSortedTrans = sortedTransactions.reverse() and console.log(reverseSortedTrans) again, will it work?

Answer (score 0):

```
const sortedTransactions = transactions.sort(
    (a, b) => b.date - a.date
  );
const reverseSortedTrans = sortedTransactions.reverse()

console.log(reverseSortedTrans)
```

I mean like this, will it work?

Comment: It doesn't function